# iPad Pro(3) M1 iOS 15.0, Code=201 "Siri and Dictation are disabled"

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

An Objective-C project of iOS. Used the Apple SpeechKit. The Speech recognition send a error 'Error Domain=kLSRErrorDomain Code=201 "Siri and Dictation are disabled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Siri and Dictation are disabled}'

An error will be reported in resultHandler: Error Domain=kLSRErrorDomain Code=201 "Siri and Dictation are disabled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Siri and Dictation are disabled}

```
- (void)resetRecognitionTask
{
    // Cancel the previous task if it's running.
    if (self.recognitionTask) {
        //[self.recognitionTask cancel]; // Will cause the system error and memory problems.
        [self.recognitionTask finish];
    }
    self.recognitionTask = nil;
    
    // Configure the audio session for the app.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (AVAudioSession.sharedInstance.categoryOptions != (AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth)) {
        [AVAudioSession.sharedInstance setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode:AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error];
    }
    //[AVAudioSession.sharedInstance setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        [self stopWithError:error];
        return;
    }
    [AVAudioSession.sharedInstance setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        [self stopWithError:error];
        return;
    }

    // Create and configure the speech recognition request.
    self.recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];
    self.recognitionRequest.taskHint = SFSpeechRecognitionTaskHintConfirmation;
    
    // Keep speech recognition data on device
    if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
        self.recognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = NO;
    }

    // Create a recognition task for the speech recognition session.
    // Keep a reference to the task so that it can be canceled.
    __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    self.speechRecognizer = nil;
    self.recognitionTask = [self.speechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:self.recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        __strong typeof(self)strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (result != nil) {
            [strongSelf resultCallback:result];
        }
    }];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an oversight of iOS system.

Solution: Settings-> General -> Keyboards -> Enable Dictation
Turn it ON.